# Changing File Attribute

Tags: linux, windows, file-attributes

I have two files in my documents currently with the `A` attribute, but I need them to be `-rw-r--r--`. Trying to modify them in command line like I would normally just gives me an invalid switch error (which I kind of expected, after looking at the available commands). Looking around on the internet for more info on `-rw-r--r--` wasn't returning anything of use, so I was hoping someone here could help?

Edit for clarification and background:

I am using the Windows 7 operating system, editing game data. I have two .plist files that are currently with the attribute `A`, and they need to have `-rw-r--r--` in order for the .ipa to upload successfully (they were originally `-rw-r--r--` but were changed to `A` upon saving).

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to understand your situation with such little information. So I have to post here because I don't have 50rep to comment.

you remove the A attr using chattr , unless the file has the immutable bit set.
so ,for example, for,

```
# lsattr toaster-hero && ls -al toaster-hero
-------A-----e-- toaster-hero
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 20:14 toaster-hero
#
```

do,

```
# chattr -A toaster-hero
# lsattr toaster-hero && ls -al toaster-hero
-------------e-- toaster-hero
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 20:14 toaster-hero
#
```

but if you have immutable bit set,

```
# chmod 755 toaster-hero && chattr +Ai toaster-hero
# lsattr toaster-hero && ls -al toaster-hero
----i--A-----e-- toaster-hero
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Aug 14 20:14 toaster-hero
```

while you can't chmod the file, you can still mod attr via chattr

```
# chmod 644 toaster-hero
chmod: changing permissions of `toaster-hero': Operation not permitted
# chattr -A toaster-hero
# lsattr toaster-hero && ls -al toaster-hero
----i--------e-- toaster-hero
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Aug 14 20:14 toaster-hero
```

so you need to lsattr the file to find out if immutable bit is set and unset it, then you can mod permissions

```
# chattr -i toaster-hero
# lsattr toaster-hero
-------------e-- toaster-hero
# lsattr toaster-hero && ls -al toaster-hero
-------------e-- toaster-hero
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Aug 14 20:14 toaster-hero
# chmod 644 toaster-hero && ls -al toaster-hero
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 14 20:14 toaster-hero
#
```

unless of course you do not have those privileges [su,sudo] , then yeah,
you have a problem.

As per your clarification see Ferruccio's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592448/c-how-to-set-file-permissions-cross-platform/593017#593017

Comment: Hi, I'm very sorry, and thank you for responding; I added more information in the original post to try and get across what I'm trying to do. So I have the files in a folder, and if I open cmd.exe, I am met with:

`C:\Users\Name>` which I navigate to `cd Documents\Data`
and the files are in that directory.

I found it odd since the windows CMD commands don't have the same attribute options, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @NHG95 Ahh okay, yeah windows sets the Archive bit automatically, if i am now understanding you correctly. I believe you can multi-select the files in question and then right click and unset the archive bit in properties all in one go. There was an old tweak/registry mod/hack for disabling the setting of archive bit but i don't know it off hand.